# Timestamp (static; precision = hh:mm:ss) in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, timestamp, excel-2013

Need your help on the timestamp function in Excel 2013.

I need to check the response time of an application and record the findings. In the past, i.e. some previous version of Excel, my method of choice was

"CTRL + Shift + : " (colon)

The duration would be calculated in a separate step, but I need the timestamps as supporting "evidence" that this is real data and not just one more general complaint.

In Excel 2013, I can still use this function, but it only shows (and calculates with) hh:mm. What I need is hh:mm:ss (no higher precision needed). Time zones are not relevant, either, as only the time differences will be of interest.

What I have tried so far, without success:

- test all kinds of "Format Cells" with Time, Custom varieties I could think of
- searched File --> Options to find a spot where I could manipulate time settings, incl. Language settings
- internet searches: have not had a closer look at any VBA solution, as I have no experience with it

The keyboard solution would be perfect for me, if only I could find the right spot to tweak the precision to show seconds, too.

Any hints?

Comment: In what version of Excel did the shortcut key include seconds? I don't have my Excel 97 documentation handy, but I'm pretty certain that it only returned hours and minutes.  As did later later versions.  Pretty sure you'll need VBA for this.

Comment: Hello Ron, not sure about the exact version, but I was using it in the year 2012, had discovered that by accident and loved it.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple macro is what you need.

```
Sub MyTimestamp()
    ActiveCell.Value = Now()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

Assign a keyboard shortcut to it (such as Ctrl + t) and away you go.

Comment: Thank you DMM, will test and may come back with a cry for help!